# input and button don't align in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I'm trying to get a text input and a button to line up in Safari 7.0.4 and it simply does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/LFFTP/

```
form {
    height: 30px;
    background: #000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
input {
    border: 0px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #900;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
button {
    border: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

<form>
    <input type="text" value="Input" />
    <button>Button</button>
</form>
```

You'll notice in Safari that the button is 1px lower (as indicated by the tiny piece of black that's visible from the form's background). I cannot find a reason or a fix for this.

[image: um yeah]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but it's to do with the vertical align.

Add:

```
input,
button {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

It seems you can just add it to the `button`, but better safe than sorry I guess.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/LFFTP/2/)**